# How can I write a google sheets script that will sort through a particular column and delete everything that is not in a specific array of strings

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Here is what I have.

```
function readRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[0] != "FACP" || row[0] == '') {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i) + 1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};


function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name: "Remove rows where column C is 0 or blank",
    functionName: "readRows"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Script Center Menu", entries);
};
```

Instead of just searching for one value "FACP", I want to have an array that is looped through and if the column does not contain what is in the array than the row will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the list of values that prevent deletion of a row, is in the array `listofValues`. Then replace your for loop with ...

```
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (listofValues.indexOf(row[0]) === -1  || row[0] == '') {
    sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i) + 1) - rowsDeleted);
    rowsDeleted++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is giving me a syntax error on the line  of the "if" statement. Any idea what it could be?